# Does anybody recognize this coordinate notation format? And how to convert to lat/lon?

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems, geo

recently I received a CSV file containing taxi services and their service area.
It's got 4 columns, taxi service, coordinate 1, coordinate 2, radius of service from that coordinate.

Example data:

Artax Eindhoven;514.792.547;565.700.960.000.004;50

A1 Limousine Service;556.375;126.416.667;50

So my problem is a coordinate like 514.792.547, 565.700.960.000.004

The notation format for the coordinates is unfamiliar to me (I only know notations with -180 to 180). I've never even seen a notation format with multiple dots per coordinate.

So maybe someone recognizes it and can help me with it's name or a wikipedia page about it, or better yet how to convert it to lat/lon?

Thanks in advance.

Vince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing here, but am I right in thinking this is for the Netherlands, in which case these coordinates might be in the Dutch RD coordinate system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_the_Netherlands (See the Statistics section)

Although the multiple decimal places do look a bit strange. Possibly WGRS (see: http://www.pdana.com/PHDWWW_files/WGRS.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, yes these 2 are in the Netherlands, but there's also data from other places in the world, like chicago. Allo Chicago Limo;418.781.136;-876.297.982;50 The multiple decimal places and the fact that it's way outside the normal ranges have me scratching my head...

Comment: I was guessing it maybe had something to do with how the software that produced the file stored coordinates internally, like geometric spacial coordinates of some kind x.y.z or something, but then again why would there be x,y,z, for both lat and long.

Comment: The format does look a bit strange. Might be best to check with whoever supplied you with the CSV file.

Comment: And do tell us what it is when you find out. You've got me curious now.

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback! I checked with the CSV supplier (who in turn checked with the developer of their CSV export), and as it turns out they actually have a bug in the CSV export functionality of their system which they're trying to fix now. I expect it has something to do with their localization (representation of numbers, decimals etc. in countries) and that resulted in the multiple dots (in Holland we use , to group thousands, in US dots). Besides that something else is wrong, just converting 565.700.960.000.004 into 56.570096 etc. still gives me wrong results. Will be fixed soon.